# Find multiline blocks

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I'm trying to find occurrences of BLOB_SMUGHO, from the file test.out from the bottom of the file. If found, return a chunk of data which I'm interested in between the string "2014.10"

> I'm getting Use of uninitialized value $cc in pattern match (m//) at

Whats is wrong with this script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use File::ReadBackwards;

my $find = "BLOB_SMUGHO";
my $chnkdelim = "\n[" . strftime "%Y.%m", localtime;

my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new('test.out', $chnkdelim, 0) or die "err-file: $!\n";

while ( defined(my $line = $fh->readline) ) {
     if(my $cc =~ /$find/){
        print $cc;
     }
}

close($fh);
```

In case if this helps, here is a sample content of test.out

```
2014.10.31 lots and 
lots of 
gibbrish 
2014.10.31 which I'm not 
interested 
in. It 
also 
2014.10.31 spans
across thousands of 
lines and somewhere in the middle there will be
2014.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and 
2014.10.31 certain other 
2014.10.31 words 
2014.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and
2014.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and
which 
I 
will 
be 
interested 
in.
```

And I'm expecting to capture all the multiple occurrences of the chunk of the text from bottom of the file.

```
2014.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have written your match incorrectly due to misunderstanding the `=~` operator:

```
if(my $cc =~ /$find/){   # incorrect, like saying   if(undef matches something)
```

If you want to match what is in `$line` against the pattern between `/.../` then do:

```
if($line =~ /$find/) {
```

The match operator expects a value on left side as well as right side. you were using it like an assignment operator.

If you need to capture the match(es) into a variable or list, then add it to the left of an equal sign:

```
if(my ($cc) = $line =~ /$find/) {       <--  wrap $cc in () for list context
```

By the way, I think you are better off writing:

```
if($line =~ /$find/) {
    print $line;
```

or if you want to print what you matched only

```
    print $0;
```

Since you aren't capturing a substring, it doesnt really matter here.

Now, as to how to match everything between two patterns, the task is easier if you don't match line by line, but match across newlines using the /s modifier.

In Perl, you can set the record separator to undef and use slurp mode.

```
local $/ = undef;
my $s = <>;        # read all lines into $s
```

Now to scan $s for patterns

```
while($s =~ /(START.*?STOP)/gsm) {  print "$1\n"; }   # print the pattern inclusive of START and STOP
```

Or to capture between START and STOP

```
while($s =~ /START(.*?)STOP/gsm) {  print "$1\n"; }   # print the pattern between of START and STOP
```

So in your case the start pattern is `2014.10.31` and stop is `BLOB_SMUGHO`

```
while($s =~ /(2014\.10\.31.*?BLOB_SMUGHO)/gsm) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

NOTE: Regex modifiers in Perl come after the last `/` so if you see I use `/gsm` for multiline, match newline, and global matching (get multiple matches in a loop by remembering the last location).

Comment: ah.. I should have posted the question before I wasted my time so long. I'm very new and today is my first day with perl! Thank you very much. On more question, when I changed the above code a little, I'm able to get the op like this

.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and 
2014

.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and
2014
any idea how can I get it like this:
2014.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and 
2014.10.31
this precious word BLOB_SMUGHO and
I understand its gotta to do with the way ReadBackwards works, is there anyway to tell ReadBackwards to read excluding the delims?

Comment: I'm getting around to the answer, my phone died and I was trying to save the initial part of the answer before moving to PC (where I am now) :( -- revising more ....

Comment: tnq vm. the reason I did not go for slurp is because I'm dealing with a large file (easily more than few thousands lines) on cpu and memory sensitive machine.

Comment: Few thousand lines is small potatoes compared to the overhead of calling the regex engine once for each line. Test it and see, I think you'll be surprised.